# treat newcommand as a symbol

Tags: math-mode, macros, subscripts

I have defined a `\newcommand`

```
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}\xspace}
```

I would like to write

[image]

For this I try:

```
\begin{equation}
     \pt_{,a}
\end{equation}
```

The error for this approach is:

```
! Double subscript.
```

If I try

```
\begin{equation}
    {\pt}_{,a}
\end{equation}
```

the result is not what is expected:

[image]

Is it possible to treat the result of `\pt` as a symbol in order to add a subscript, or is there any other solution that does not require cloning the contents of `\pt` into the `equation`?

Comment: You can make `\pt` a math atom by wrapping it in, for instance `\mathord`: `\newcommand{\pt}{\mathord{\ensuremath{p_{T}}}\xspace}`, or `\mathop`, depending on what it means...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, your solution adds `\xspace` into the combined subscript.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what would be the correct placement for `\xspace` here... I would go for a command that uses `\xspace` only if not in math-mode. Or better, I wouldn't use `\xspace` at all. And I would insert a negative kern before the `_{,a}` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with the “embellishment” argument type of `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pt}{e{_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{p^{}_{T}}{p^{}_{T,#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\pt$

$\pt_{a}$

\end{document}
```

I left out `\ensuremath` and `\xspace`, of course; such a command is for *math*, so there's no reason to allow it outside math formulas. And this avoids all the quirks associated to `\xspace` (which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't).

[image]

In this particular case you may want to tuck the comma a bit into T:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pt}{e{_}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{p^{}_{T}}{p^{}_{T,#1}}%
}
```

[image]

The same output as in the second case can also be obtained with “classical” methods:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pt}{\@ifnextchar_{\pt@plus}{p^{}_{T}}}
\def\pt@plus_#1{p^{}_{T\!,#1}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest variation on your MWE that I can think of is

```
\newcommand*{\pt}[1]{\ensuremath{p_{T,#1}}\xspace}
```

which you could then invoke as

```
\pt{a}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use neither \ensuremath nor \xspace in such a definition.